# How to fetch a URL containing a # with Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, fetch-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API and to fetch the events of a calendar, you must send a GET request to the https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events endpoint.

Problem is `calendarId` may contain a `#` like in `addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com` and when when I fetch https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com/events, it's only actually fetching https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/addressbook, i.e. the part of the URL before the `#` (I see it in the Chrome Network tab and I just get `GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/addressbook 404` in the console)

So how can I force the fetch() method to use the entire URL ?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example] the Google api js client library should be handling this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to percent-encode the `calendarId`:

```
> encodeURIComponent("addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com")
"addressbook%23contacts%40group.v.calendar.google.com"
```